# How the user is authenticated in SharePoint using Active Directory?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, web-part, active-directory, solution-deployment, password

I am having a requirement when admin sets an account to "Force Password change at next login", the user will be redirected to password reset page.

But I don't know what happens at the back after user provides credentials.

At the time, if an account is set to "Force Password change at next login", the user simply cannot login to SharePoint.

I want to detect if the user account is set to "Force Password change at next login" then the user will be redirected to change password page.

I saw a soluion at http://changepassword.codeplex.com/ but it allows an authenticated user.

Answer (score 1):

To access so early in the Authentication process is not easy and I think you need a custom Farm Solution with a own Authentication Provider.

One way to solve this with Microsoft Tools is ADFS ([ADFS 2012 R2 now supports Password Change (not reset) across all devices](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/samueld/archive/2015/05/13/adfs-2012-r2-now-supports-password-change-not-reset-across-all-devices.aspx)). But setting up a SharePoint with ADFS is in some environments not easy and there are many thinks to plan before doing so.

Comment: I am using SharePoint Server 2013. Seems like the link you provided works with SharePoint Online version. Is this right?

Comment: @Kamalpreet: The link is purely ADFS. For more info see [msdn: Active Directory Federation Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb897402.aspx). ADFS is a extra Server you have to install and configure in your environment. Then you can use this for Authentication.